# Selecting the last node with a child node

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

Hi I wanted to know if there was some handy criteria I could use in order to select the last node with a child node. For example:

```
<Results>
    <Result Number="1"/>
    <Result Number="2">
        <Subresult>a</Subresult>
    </Result>
    <Result Number="3"/>
    <Result Number="4">
        <Subresult>a</Subresult>
    </Result>
    <Result Number="5"/>
    <Result Number="6"/>
</Results>
```

In the above example I am interested in picking node number 4 because it is the last node with a child node.

I am hoping there is some handy way of doing this instead of having to throw it into a for-each or something, like with a Criteria or something or a set of criterias.

Hope my question and example makes sense!

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you filter those who have a node (*), from that set you get the last element. Won't get elements that have text instead of child nodes.

```
(//Result[*])[last()]
```

Tested in [this](http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output).